Remove "set as desktop background" in Explorer Context Menu (works with below method) but still shows under (Show more options)
When you right click on a .avci, .avcs, .avif, .avifs, .bmp, .dib, .gif, .heic, .heics, .heif, .heifs, .hif, .jfif, .jpe, .jpeg, .jpg, .png, .tif, .tiff, or .wdp image file, you can use the Set as desktop background context menu item to quickly set that image as your new desktop background wallpaper.
I am able to remove this option in Windows 11 after doing the below but the option to 'Set as Background' still appears under the "Show more Options" area of the Context menu. Can somoone please help me.
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.avci\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.avcs\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.avif\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.avifs\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.bmp\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.dib\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.gif\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.heic\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.heics\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.heif\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.heifs\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.hif\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jfif\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jpe\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jpeg\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.png\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.tif\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.tiff\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wdp\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper]


